# How to draw PDF Context in Cocoa

Tags: macos, pdf, cocoa, draw, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to save PDF file with `NSView` objects.
Here is implementation of `Square` class (subclass of `NSView`).

```
@implementation Square

- (id)initWithColor:(NSColor *)aColor;
{
if (self = [super init])
{
    self.frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    self.color = aColor;
}
return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
[self.color set];
NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

}
```

Here is part of implementation of my `DrawView` - sublcass of `NSView`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
squareGroup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)addSquare:(Square *)square
{
[squareGroup addObject:square];
[self addSubview:square];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
[[NSColor whiteColor] set];
NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}
```

I can click on button `Red` or `Blue` and add `Square` object with blue or red color and when i clicked `Save` i want to save White `DrawView` with `Square` objects on it. I can move `Square` objects on `DrawView` now so every single `Square` objects are on different places.

My saving method look like below (in `DrawView` class):

```
- (void)saveAsPDF
{
NSString *homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory();
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[homeDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.pdf"]];

CGRect mediaBox = self.bounds;
CGContextRef ctx = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)(fileURL), &mediaBox, NULL);

CGPDFContextBeginPage(ctx, NULL);

for (Square *square in squareGroup) {
    [square.layer renderInContext:ctx];
}

[self.layer renderInContext:ctx];

CGPDFContextEndPage(ctx);
CFRelease(ctx);
}
```

In result i've got only blank file in home directory.

What is wrong with my save method? How can i do it correclty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a very helpful tutorial [here](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000074.php) that may help you

they suggest two ways: the first is this, but the second one is more comprehensive and is well worth a look.

```
(void)didEnd:(NSSavePanel *)sheet
returnCode:(int)code
saveFormat:(void *)saveType
{
if (code == NSOKButton)
{
    if (pageIt)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        NSRect r = [textView bounds];
        NSData *data = [textView dataWithPDFInsideRect:r];

        [data writeToFile:[sheet filename] atomically:YES];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your sample paste here working correclty but i read this from hyperlink too. thanks.

Comment: happy to help. it's always a good idea to post code just in case links break! :)

Comment: Is possible to make multiple pages with this method?

Comment: i don't know i haven't tested it out. i think you can with the 2nd method.